# How can I make this javascript function not use a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

This `function` toggles the active state of a hamburger icon when clicking on it. Also clicking anywhere on the document does the same but only if the dropdown is open.

```
var dropdownOpen = false;

$(".hamburger").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('.hamburger')) {
            return;
        }
        else if (dropdownOpen === true)
        {
            $(".hamburger").toggleClass('is-active');
            dropdownOpen = false;
        }
    });
});
```

How would I go about combining two click events so I don't have to use a global variable?

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropdownOpen = false;

    $(document).click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('.hamburger')) {
            $('.hamburger').toggleClass('is-active');
            dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen;
        }
        else if (dropdownOpen === true)
        {
            $(".hamburger").toggleClass('is-active');
            dropdownOpen = false;
        }
    });
});
```

..but it didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: The function you are passing, give it a name. Attach a prototype property and use that each time you want to toggle

Comment: The second version is missing the `$(".hamburger").click()` handler. If you add that into the `document.ready` function it should work.

Comment: Why are you doing `if (dropdownOpen === true)`? Just use `if (dropdownOpen)`, because if the expression is not true, it is false.

Comment: Why do you need the global variable? Just use `if ($(".hambuger").hasClass("is-active"))`

Comment: or get rid of the `if` entirely, and just do `$(".hamburger").removeClass("is-active")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all your JS in an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). All the JS variables are not scoped to this function expression instead of being available globally.

```
(function() {
  var dropdownOpen = false;

  $(".hamburger").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen;
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).is('.hamburger')) {
        return;
      } else if (dropdownOpen === true) {
        $(".hamburger").toggleClass('is-active');
        dropdownOpen = false;
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I've not heard of an Immediately Invoked Function Expression before. Will be useful to know in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the global varable at all.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".hamburger")) {
        $(e.target).toggleClass("is-active");
    } else {
        $(".hambuger").removeClass("is-active");
    }
}
```

There's no harm in calling `removeClass()` if the class isn't there.